# Skype - ActionScript error message

Tags: skype

Long time my Skype worked well.
This morning, on loading, I got a popup window with this message:

```
Adobe Flash Player
An ActionScript error has occurred

SecurityError: Error #2060: Security sandbox violation: ExternalInterface caller https://connect.facebook.net/rsrc.php/v1/yS/r/NoZWYE2GRkt.swf cannot access https://apps.skype.com/home/?uiversion=6.11.0.102&language=en.
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/_initJS()
    at flash.external::ExternalInterface$/call()
    at Xdm/log()
    at Xdm()
```

What is the reason, and what should I do, pls?

Comment: First step verify your running the current version of Skype.

Comment: @Ramhound, yes it is current version - 6.11.0.102. Click Help - Check for Updates says that it is current version installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try a couple things.  First, revoke authorization via facebook security settings, then reauthorize skype through the Skype program preferably.  Second, remove Flash and Skype, restart, then reinstall Flash, then Skype.  This is most likely related to either a bad authorization from facebook, or a corrupted install of skype or flash.